# pseudo element not sitting outside div with overflow hidden

Tags: css

i have a div with overflow-y: hidden; and a have a pseudo element to the right of the buttons that i want to position outside the div but it will not work. here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PAdSd/1/.

But if i give the div no overflow it will sit out of the div fine.   Here is that fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PAdSd/2/.

Any help would be wonderful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `position: relative` from `.nav`. You can see the results in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/uxy2G/).

A similar problem had me banging my head against the wall for days. Trial and error and pure chance produced the solution. Not sure about cross browser compatibility, but it works in chrome and firefox (as long as you prefix your css3 properties with `-moz`).

Comment: thats cool, but i need elements inside nav that are absolutely positioned.

Comment: You could wrap `.nav` in a div with `position:relative` as you can [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/yatSy/). It's a bit div soupish, but it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: yeh, that is pretty dodgy.  Last resort stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of solving this problem (especially useful when you can't just remove position:relative because of say, using height:100%; on the pseudo element):

To make the content visible, add padding to the bottom, say 10px;
Then to remove the paddings effect for other elements use margin-bottom:-10px;

So:

```
.nav{
    background: transparent;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    /*new stuff*/
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hidden because that is what you have told it to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/PAdSd/3/

If you don't want it hidden, but still want overflow hidden then you will need to reposition it higher. `.nav:after` will put content at the end, but inside of the nav tag.

You can position it higher by adjusting the top css value.

```
.nav:after{
    content: "";
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #000;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    top: 10px;
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 0px #8f0222;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Or you might want to use body:after instead, because it doesn't sound like you actually want it inside the nav bar.

Comment: i need it below the nav and i need the nav to have overflow hidden

Comment: @AndrewMilson - then you can't place it inside the navbar. Shrug. Can you place it in body instead? You can wrap it in another div, but it has to go somewhere - http://jsfiddle.net/PAdSd/4/